# How to receive and display POST parameters sent to ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post

I am trying to receive a `HTTP POST` from **Mirth Connect** in my **ASP.NET MVC** solution but I don´t know how this data comes to my web application. I create a controller to receive it:

```
public class IntegrationController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var c = HttpContext.CurrentHandler;
        var v = c.ToString();
        Console.Write("The value is" + v);

        return View();
    }
}
```

What should I receive in `Index()`? A dictionary? And once I receive it, how to how it in the viewer?

Thank you.

Comment: Create a C# class which can represent the data coming in and use that s the parameter. Model binder will be able to map the posted data(assuming it matches the naming requirements) and you can use parameter to pass data to view as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [FromBody] Annotation, then I can treat the incoming like any other parameter.

```
    [Route("api/gateways")]
    [Route("api/connectedDevices")]
    [Route("api/v0/gateways")]
    [Route("api/v0/connectedDevices")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Create([FromBody] IGatewayNewOrUpdate device,
```

I do have a case when I read the content directly from the Request;

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage AddImageToScene(long id, string type)
    {
        SceneHandler handler = null;

        try
        {

            var content = Request.Content;
```

I think it may be a little different for different versions, but I hope that will give you  a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. This will work, if v is the name of a field that will be posted from a form.

```
public class DataModel
{
    public string v {get; set;}
}

public class IntegrationController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(DataModel model)
    {
        Console.Write("The value is" + model.v);

        return View();
    }
}
```

If you receive Json then a can add `[FromBody]`

```
public class IntegrationController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index([FromBody] DataModel model)
    {
        Console.Write("The value is" + model.v);

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @rboe. Yes, this works very good. I create a specific model in my folder Model to define the  DataModel class. Does it make sense? I mean, from there I can for exemple store data in my database or show it in the View.